# Inner-Join on two column where one column has a single tailing character

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Hi I'm new to SQL and I have 2 tables that I am trying to do an inner-join with.

```
------------------------
First table: 
------------------------
ID-Number   CustomerName 


------------------------
Second table
------------------------
ID-Number   CustomerDevice

(ID with a single tailing character)
```

**Questions**

What would be the best preforming way to execute the inner-join on both table's ID-number?

Is there a method to remove the trailing character within the inner-join command?

Comment: Post ([edit]) your sample data and the desired result.

Comment: When you say best, what are you really asking for? Best performing way to handle this? Easiest? How many records in each table approx.?

Comment: I mean the best performing execution. There is 15000 records in each table.

Comment: what rdbms? seems like a function based index or equivalent on the left most characters of ID-Number (for length of ID-Num-1) in second table would allow the join to be performed most efficiently.  Assuming of course that ID-Number represent the same values in both tables.  (they are what we should join on..)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The data set is in MS-SQL

Comment: MsSQL uses [Computed Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) that you could then [index](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933138(v=sql.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much choice.  Here is how you can express the logic:

```
select . . .
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id like t2.id + '_';
```

Unfortunately, this may not make use of indexes.  (Also note that `+` for string concatenation is SQL Server-specific).

You might be able to rewrite the query as:

```
     on t1.id = left(t2.id, len(t2.id) - 1)
```

This should be able to use an index on `t1(id)`.

The best approach is to fix the data, so your ids are the same type, same length, and have a properly declared foreign key relationship.  Another alternative available in SQL Server is an index on a computed column:

```
alter table t2 add realId as (left(id, len(id) - 1));
create index idx_t2_realId on t2(realId);
```

Then write the `join` logic using `realId`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
SELECT
ID-Number,
CustomerName,
CustomerDevice
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.ID-Number=LEFT(t2.ID-Number,LEN(t2.ID-Number)-1)
```

EDIT: Forgot the 1

Answer (score 0):

Given that the table **Customer** has this column

```
ID_number int not null;
```

And the the table **Device** has this column

```
ID_number varchar(15);
```

And we know that **Device**.**ID_number**, if it is not NULL, is always equal to some **Customer**.**ID_number** with a letter appended, then (SQL Server):

```
SELECT *
    FROM Customer c
    JOIN Device d
        ON c.ID_number = CAST(SUBSTRING(i.ID_number, 1, LEN(i.ID_number) - 1) AS int)
```

More robust solutions that allow for more possibilities in the data require more defensive coding. You may want to define a scalar function to process **Customer**.**ID_number**.

Comment: The customers ID_number is defined as nvarchar(100) while the customer device is nvarchar(40). I can only do queries to the system and cannot manipulate the tables within the database since it is not my application's system.

Comment: When i try this i get:
The conversion of the nvarchar value '125524041100000493' overflowed an int column.

Comment: With a value that large, use bigint or numeric(n).